# I'm looking for a book about clones in a murder mystery

Tags: story-identification, books

It sticks in my mind that it was one of the golden age/ transition sci-fi authors, but I can't remember who.

The basic story was clones being murdered, and as it dies, the clone's final moments are shared with the others in over a psychic link/ merge. If I remember correctly, it was a clone, either lost or stolen, from the facility they were all produced in.

The reason I'm thinking golden age or shortly after, is that from what I remember, the style was reminiscent of Alfred Bester, or Heinlein.

Comment: :) Post that as an answer, explaining why it matches.

Comment: I posted a placeholder answer. Feel free to copy any or all of it and then @ me in a comment so I can deleted my answer.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots thank you for the answer. Murphy's Law at its finest. I've been trying to remember the title for over a week, then it hits me 10 minutes after posting lol

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In case Chris does not return, he found his answer to be Part 2 of Roger Zelazney's *[Today We Choose Faces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Today_We_Choose_Faces)*.

> ... The narrator is a member of some secret cabal scattered throughout the House, a series of artificial environments where people live, never seeing the outdoors. It seems this cabal is in charge of the House, and someone is killing the members one by one.
>
> Each death jolts the others, so they are evidently clones. (As described earlier in the novel, cloning can be accomplished, although clones have some unexplained psychic connection to each other). One of the cabal is the Nexus, the one who can interface with the computer that seems to run everything. Each time a Nexus is killed his consciousness transfers to another member. The narration passes from one Nexus to the next as the killer works his way through his list. Each one gets the memories of his predecessor at the moment of death.